# Full text index on view with combined unique index

Tags: sql, search, view, indexing, full-text-search

Update: I never found a solution to this, so I went about this in a different way. I now copy the searchable data to a another table (that references my first table) and added a full text index on that data. Works well.

---

I want to create a full text index on a schemabound view with multiple inner joins. So I've created a unique clustered index.

```
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex_OnID] ON [dbo].[MyView]
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [OtherTableID] ASC,
    [YetAnotherTableID] ASC,
    [SomeTableID] ASC
)
```

I have to create a combined index because I've got one-to-many references.
But when I try to create the full text index I get the infamous "A unique column must be defined on this table/view." error message.

Why? Is there a way around this?

The view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TransportView]
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
SELECT        t.ID, t.BookingNr, t.CreatedBy, t.UpdatedBy, t.UpdatedByToken, t.EjerVirksomhed, t.InteressentVirksomhed, t.KundeVirksomhed, t.Disponent, t.Tilstand, t.FragtbrevNummer, t.ExternalBookingId, t.BookingDato, 
                         t.ModtagerTelefonnummer, t.ConvertedTime, t.OprettetFraFragtbrev, t.FragtbrevMangler, t.IsSynchronized, t.Tag, t.BestillerTelefonnummer, t.AfsenderReference, t.Reference1, t.Reference2, t.Reference3, 
                         t.Reference4, t.FragtBetaler, t.Mandag, t.Tirsdag, t.Onsdag, t.Torsdag, t.Fredag, t.BookingNummer, t.Fragtbrevsnumre, t.Created, t.Updated, t.LastUsedAsStaaende, t.TransportStatus, t.Oprindelsessted, 
                         t.FragtbrevForAlle, t.Frankatur, t.GeoLookupDone, t.Modtagerkundenummer, t.Natlevering, t.Returgods, t.BookingImporttype, t.ServiceKode, t.SkjultForDisponenter, t.IsKurer, t.Tags, t.StatusReplyQueue, 
                         t.ModtagerÅbningstid, t.LaesseBemaerkning, t.BookingContentVersion, t.BookingVersion, t.BookingOpdateret, t.TransportType, t.OprindeligTransportType, t.MasterBookingNummer, t.Fragtbrevstype, 
                         t.Bestillerkundenummer, t.Partigods, t.LossesIHal, t.PartigodsFraFC1, t.EjendeVirksomhed, t.DisponerendeVirksomhed, t.HijackedBy, t.HijackedTimestamp, t.BestillerFirmaNavn, t.BestillerAdresse, 
                         t.BestillerStednavn, t.BestillerPostnummer, t.BestillerBy, t.BestillerLand, t.BestillerFirmaTelefon, t.BestillerKontaktNavn, t.BestillerKontaktTelefon, t.BestillerKontaktEmail, t.BestillerKOBNr, t.BestillerRef1, 
                         t.BestillerLat, t.BestillerLon, t.BestillerLatLonPrecision, t.BestillerAdresseHashCode, t.AfhentningFirmaNavn, t.AfhentningFirmaNavn2, t.AfhentningAdresse, t.AfhentningStednavn, t.AfhentningPostnummer, 
                         t.AfhentningBy, t.AfhentningLand, t.AfhentningFirmaTelefon, t.AfhentningKontaktNavn, t.AfhentningKontaktTelefon, t.AfhentningKontaktEmail, t.AfhentningBemaerkning, t.AfhentningBemaerkning2, 
                         t.AfhentningLoadPoint, t.AfhentningLat, t.AfhentningLon, t.AfhentningLatLonPrecision, t.AfhentningAdresseHashCode, t.ModtagerFirmaNavn, t.ModtagerFirmaNavn2, t.ModtagerAdresse, t.ModtagerStednavn, 
                         t.ModtagerPostnummer, t.ModtagerBy, t.ModtagerLand, t.ModtagerFirmaTelefon, t.ModtagerKontaktNavn, t.ModtagerKontaktTelefon, t.ModtagerKontaktEmail, t.ModtagerBemaerkning, t.ModtagerBemaerkning2, 
                         t.ModtagerUnloadPoint, t.ModtagerLat, t.ModtagerLon, t.ModtagerLatLonPrecision, t.ModtagerAdresseHashCode, t.ModtagerAabningstid, t.ModtagerLukketid, t.AfsenderNavn, t.AfsenderNavn2, t.AfsenderAdresse, 
                         t.AfsenderAdresse2, t.AfsenderPostnummer, t.AfsenderBy, t.AfsenderLand, t.AfsenderTelefon, t.AfsenderEmail, t.AfsenderKundenummer, t.AfsenderKontaktperson, t.TransportDataBemaerkning, 
                         t.TransportDataBemaerkning2, t.TransportDataFragtbrevsBemaerkning, t.TransportDataTotalPallepladser, t.TransportDataTotalLadMeter, t.TransportDataFM1Rute, t.TransportDataFM2Rute, t.TransportDataFC1, 
                         t.TransportDataFC1Navn, t.TransportDataFC2, t.TransportDataFC2Navn, t.TransportDataByttepaller, t.TransportDataHelpaller, t.TransportDataHalvpaller, t.TransportDataKvartpaller, 
                         t.TransportDataForsendelsestype, t.TransportDataTvungenColliscanning, t.TransportDataEfterkravBeloeb, t.TransportDataEfterkravValuta, t.TransportDataEfterkravKontant, t.TransportDataForsikringType, 
                         t.TransportDataForsikringBeloeb, t.TransportDataForsikringValuta, t.TransportDataMaerkeNr, ben.TransportBenId, ben.BookingNrB, ben.FragtbrevnummerB, ben.BookingDatoB, ben.TurNr, ben.UpdatedTime, 
                         ben.UpdatedByB, ben.TransportBenNummer, ben.Type, ben.ExternalBookingIdB, ben.CreatedB, ben.TilstandB, ben.Label, ben.LaesseZone, ben.Status, ben.StatusText, ben.Chauffoer, ben.Tur, ben.SendtTilPda, 
                         ben.TidsAfhentning, ben.Tidslevering, ben.Lat, ben.Lon, ben.Sampletime, ben.DelafhentningAfhentet, ben.DelafhentningRest, ben.TidsLeveringTidligstDato, ben.TidsLeveringTidligstTid, 
                         ben.TidsLeveringSenestDato, ben.TidsLeveringSenestTid, ben.ETARequired, ben.AdviceOnETA, ben.SMSAdvisering, ben.EMailAdvisering, ben.Rute, ben.Fragtcentralkode, ben.PictureCount, ben.AfhSenestDato, 
                         ben.AfhSenestTID, ben.AfhTidligstDato, ben.AfhTidligstTID, ben.TransportSortOrder, ben.Materielnummer, ben.MaterielType, ben.EksterntMateriel, ben.UpdatedB, ben.Afhentningstid, ben.Klartid, ben.Lukketid, 
                         ben.OprindeligKlartid, ben.OprindeligLukketid, ben.LeveringDato, ben.LeveringKlartid, ben.LeveringLukketid, ben.OprindeligLeveringDato, ben.OprindeligLeveringKlartid, ben.OprindeligLeveringLukketid, 
                         ben.BookingDato_ForSearch, ben.SavedHash, ben.FaktiskLeveringDato, ben.FaktiskLeveringTid, ben.OprindeligMaterielnummer, ben.OprindeligEksterntMateriel, ben.TildeltUdkoerendeAnsvarlig, 
                         ben.Placeringsbeskrivelse, ben.ExcludeFromBundles, ben.IsInBundle, ben.BundleGuid, ben.DesignatedList, ben.Videresendt, ben.SliptidCountDownStarted, ben.SliptidElapsedSeconds, ben.HasBounced, 
                         ben.SliptidUdloeber, ben.SliptidEnabled, ben.EjendeVirksomhedB, ben.DisponerendeVirksomhedB, ben.OprindeligDisponerendeVirksomhed, ben.InteressentVirksomhedB, ben.KundeVirksomhedB, 
                         ben.DisponentB, ben.DisponentName, god.TransportGodsId, god.BookingNrG, god.Antal, god.Art, god.Indhold, god.Vaegt, god.Rumfang, god.Ladmeter, god.Laengde, god.Bredde, god.Hoejde, god.Stabelbar, 
                         god.MarkAndNumber, [var].TransportGodsVarelinjeId, [var].V_GodsId, [var].IndholdGv, [var].AntalGv, [var].VaegtGv, [var].LBH, [var].Ekstra
FROM            dbo.Transport AS t INNER JOIN
                         dbo.TransportBen AS ben ON t.BookingNr = ben.BookingNrB INNER JOIN
                         dbo.TransportGods AS god ON t.BookingNr = god.BookingNrG INNER JOIN
                         dbo.TransportGodsVarelinje AS [var] ON god.TransportGodsId = [var].V_GodsId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create primary key or unique index for your VIEW.

If you wants create to full-text search on a table or view, it must have a unique, single-column, non-nullable index.

This is the reason you are getting the Error.

I will  strongly encourage you to watch this video on Indexed views
[Very Good Video on Indexed views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvW_TCQnrKw&index=41&list=PL08903FB7ACA1C2FB)

Please Check Below link.
This Link will surely help you.
[Detailed Full Text Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486703/enable-full-text-search-on-view-with-inner-join)

Comment: That's what I've done. The code above creates an index on my view. Except it isn't single column. I haven't found any documentation that states it must be single column.

Comment: Please share your view that you created because there  are lots of rules that you need to follow to create an index on it. If you want to look that all rules you can refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms191432.aspx

Comment: If possible please share the view that you have created

Comment: I've added the view. A bit big but nothing fancy.

Comment: @pow I have checked your view. It really has no problem dud

Comment: Exactly, that's why I don't understand I can't create the full text index.

Comment: @Pow Please share that full text index code I will tr my best to solve your query.

Comment: I'm actually just right-clicking the view and trying to create the index with the full-text index wizard. And it's the wizard that gives me the error message "A unique column must be defined on this table/view."

Comment: Please share that code also If possible i will try my level best to resolve the issue